# No libuv when publishing portable app

Tags: asp.net-core

According to this documentation when publishing a portable app with a native dependency should produce a folder for each RID with the native bits.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/app-types

When I publish the portable app with ASP.NET Core 1.0 with preview 2 tools and a dependency on Kestrel I don't see the folders for libuv. But the application runs.

What's going on?